# menu home item stay's on every page

Tags: routes

i made a site through artisteer and i wanted to have a different background on each page, i did this with themekey and it worked.
My layout is a header, content and left sidebar with main menu.
The problem is that when i'm on the home page the home menu item is correct and located in the sidebar...when i 'm on the other pages the home menu item is located above the contentblok instead of the left sidebar....what can i do to remove from every page the home item so it only appears in the menul ist in the left sidebar..
Thx in advance 
Greetz
fred

Comment: Do you know how to write CSS?  It's likely that the CSS generated by Artisteer is not 100% accurate for Drupal, as their platform has to support Joomla and Wordpress as well.  However, using Firebug or another web developer tool, you should be able to check the CSS on the home page and then fix it in your theme for the other pages.  Otherwise, you should take this up with Artisteer support.  If they sold you a product, they should support it.

Comment: Thx Patrick,But i think it has more to do with drupal, how can i place the home menu item to the main menu situated in the left sidebar? at this moment only the homepage has a correct layout the other pages, the home item is visible in the correct left sidebar menu BUT also above the content blok of my pages..

Comment: As you said, you have used themekey for different layout on different page. It mean, you have different theme for different page of the site. So, you need to display block from the block administration page in theme implemented for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the blocks administration page and checking which blocks/menus are being shown where?  This will allow you to locate the one that you don't want displayed; if it's a menu, you can then go to the menu administration page, find the menu in question, and delete the home page link from it.

Make sure you visit the administration page for the theme that is causing the problem; block placement is configured separately for each theme.

Comment: Thx Patrick, i will check this later today.